# Root User Docker

Tags: docker

I understand that it's considered a bad security practice to run Docker images as root, but I have a specific situation that I wanted to pass by the community to see if anyone can help.

We are currently using a pipeline on an Amazon Linux 2 instance with a single user called ec2-user. Unfortunately, a lot of the scripts we're using for our pipeline have hard-coded paths baked in (notably `/home/ec2-user/`) ... which may or may not reference the `$HOME` variable.

I've been talking to one of the engineers that is building a Docker image for our pipeline and suggested that he creates a new user entirely so root user isn't running our pipeline.

For example:

```
# add clip user

RUN groupadd-r clip && useradd -r -g clip clip

# disable root

RUN chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin root

# set environment variables

ENV HOME /home/clip

ENV DEBIAN FRONTEND-noninteractive
```

However, the engineer mentioned that the clip user inside the container will have some uid that may or may not exist in the host machine.  For example, if the clip user had uid 1001 in the container, but 1001 was john in the host, all the files created as the clip user inside the container would be owned by john on the outside.

Further, he is more concerned about the situation where the clip user has a uid in the container that doesn’t exist in the host’s passwd.  In that case files created by the clip user in the container would be owned by a bare unassociated uid on the host.

If we decided to pass in ids from the host as the user/group to run the image.  The kernel will be ok with it (same kernel as the host), and when all is said and done files created inside the container will then be owned by the user/group you pass in. However, the container wouldn’t know who that user/group are, so it’ll just use the raw ids, and stuff like $HOME or whoami won’t work.

With that said, we're curious if anyone else has experienced these problems and if anyone has found solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you say is totally normal.  The container has its own `/etc/passwd` file, and so a given numeric user ID might map to different user names (or to not at all) in the host and in the container.  Beyond some cosmetic issues around debug shells, it shouldn't usually matter if the current numeric uid is actually present in the container `/etc/passwd`, and there's no reason a container uid would need to be mapped in the host `/etc/passwd`.

Note that there are a couple of ways to directly assume another user ID in Docker, either using the `docker run -u` option or the Dockerfile `USER` directive.  The `RUN chsh` command you propose doesn't really do anything and doesn't prevent becoming root inside a container.

> clip user inside the container will have some uid that may or may not exist in the host machine.

True, totally normal.

> For example, if the clip user had uid 1001 in the container, but 1001 was john in the host, all the files created as the clip user inside the container would be owned by john on the outside.

This is partially true, but only in the case where you've explicitly mapped a host directory into the container with a `docker run -v` option.  Otherwise, the host user with uid 1001 won't be able to navigate to the `/var/lib/docker/...` directory that actually contains the container files, so it doesn't matter that they could hypothetically write them.

The more usual case around this is to explicitly supply a host uid so that the container process can save its state in a mapped host directory.  Pass a numeric uid to the `docker run -u` option; there's no particular need for that uid to exist in the container's `/etc/passwd`.

```sh
docker run \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$PWD/data:/data" \
  ...
```

> the container wouldn’t know who that user/group are, so it’ll just use the raw ids, and stuff like $HOME or whoami won’t work.

Unless your application explicitly calls these things, they won't usually matter.  "Home directory" is a pretty poorly defined concept in a Docker container since it's usually a wrapper around a single process.